# JQUERY to show a div that was hidden on CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html, hidden

Maybe I should have asked this way earlier...

I have a DIV that loads all items from a sql table. Then I have some checkboxes that will be used to filter by color, so if a user picks BLUE the DIV will be reloaded passing BLUE as the color and showing only BLUE items.

Once the user clicks, I would like to show a "loading" .gif during the time elapsed while loading the BLUE items. Maybe it's super short or maybe it takes 3 seconds or so...

My options are:

- Having another DIV inside my main DIV that contains the .gif and is CSS non displayed. Then with a JQUERY I would have to display it and then hide it... If this option is good, what kind of JQUERY could i use?
- Using a JQUERY to .load the Loading DIV before I load the results after filtering

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the [BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#page) jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is to have the div in the page, usually near the bottom of the page, hidden with css:

```
<div id="loading">
    <img src="img/loading.gif" alt="Loading." />
</div>
```

css:

```
#loading {
    display:none;
    /* some more code to position the div where you want */
}
```

js:

```
$("#loading").toggle(); // or .show() / .hide()
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gwmah/

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of useful function provided b jQuery to display html elements

- hide() show()
- toggle()

  ```
  //your css would be like this
  #divToDisplay {
      display:none;
  }

  $('document').ready(function() {

      $('#divToDisplay').show();
  });

  //or to make it show hide on click use toggle()
  $('document').ready(function() {

       $('#divToDisplay').toggle();
  });

  //you can also use slideToggle() to give some animation for show and hide
  $('document').ready(function() { 

      $('#divToDisplay').slideToggle( "slow" );
  }
  ```